# Three MySQL requests with php on different positions in one file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

on my MySQL database are 3 different tables: album, singles, upcoming. I want to embed all three via php. Only the first table, which I embeded works with the following code, the other one doesn't:

```
<div id="album_releases" class="animated bounceIn">

            <div id="headline">Latest Favorite Album Releases</div>

            <div id="frame" class="frame">

            <ul class="slidee">

                <li><div id="datebox"><span style="padding-top:50px;">Oct<br />2013</span></div></li>    

                            <?php

                $sql = "SELECT artist, releasename, label, date, img, spotify, nas, itunes FROM album ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40";

                $db_erg = $db_link->query( $sql );


                function ausgabe($daten) {
                    echo "<li><div id='blurbox'><div class='blur img'><div class='img-wrap'><div class='img-info'>";
                    echo "". $daten->artist ."<br />";
                    echo "". $daten->releasename ."<br />";
                    echo "". $daten->label ."<br />";
                    echo "". $daten->date ."<br />";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "<img class='hover' width='168' height='168' src=". $daten->img .">";
                    echo "</div></div></div><div id='caption'>";
                    echo "<img src='images/spotifyicon.png' style='float:left;'><a href='". $daten->spotify ."'>Listen on Spotify</a><br />";
                    echo "<div id='element_sep'>-</div>";
                    echo "<img src='images/servericon.png' style='float:left;'><a href='". $daten->nas ."'>Listen on toegrNAS</a><br />";
                    echo "<div id='element_sep'>-</div>";
                    echo "<img src='images/itunesicon.png' style='float:left;'><a href='". $daten->itunes ."'>Listen/Buy on iTunes</a>";
                    echo "</div></li>";
                }

                while($daten = $db_erg->fetch_object()) {
                    ausgabe($daten);
                }

                ?>

            </ul>

          </div>          

          <div id="overlay_left">-</div>

          <div id="overlay_right">-</div>

        </div>

        <div id="single_releases" class="animated bounceIn">

            <div id="headline">Latest Favorite Single Releases</div>

            <div id="frame" class="frame">

            <ul class="slidee">

                <li><div id="datebox"><span style="padding-top:50px;">Oct<br />2013</span></div></li>

                            <?php

                $sql = "SELECT artist, releasename, label, date, img, spotify, nas, itunes FROM single ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40";

                $db_erg = $db_link->query( $sql );


                function ausgabe($daten) {
                    echo "<li><div id='blurbox'><div class='blur img'><div class='img-wrap'><div class='img-info'>";
                    echo "". $daten->artist ."<br />";
                    echo "". $daten->releasename ."<br />";
                    echo "". $daten->label ."<br />";
                    echo "". $daten->date ."<br />";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "<img class='hover' width='168' height='168' src=". $daten->img .">";
                    echo "</div></div></div><div id='caption'>";
                    echo "<img src='images/spotifyicon.png' style='float:left;'><a href='". $daten->spotify ."'>Listen on Spotify</a><br />";
                    echo "<div id='element_sep'>-</div>";
                    echo "<img src='images/servericon.png' style='float:left;'><a href='". $daten->nas ."'>Listen on toegrNAS</a><br />";
                    echo "<div id='element_sep'>-</div>";
                    echo "<img src='images/itunesicon.png' style='float:left;'><a href='". $daten->itunes ."'>Listen/Buy on iTunes</a>";
                    echo "</div></li>";
                }

                while($daten = $db_erg->fetch_object()) {
                    ausgabe($daten);
                }

?>    

            </ul>

          </div>          

          <div id="overlay_left">-</div>

          <div id="overlay_right">-</div>

        </div>

        <div id="upcoming_releases" class="animated bounceIn">

            <div id="headline">Upcoming Releases</div>  

                    <div class="content">

                        <div id="release_element">

                                        <?php
            require_once ('mysql-config.php');

            $db_link = mysqli_connect (
                                     MYSQL_HOST, 
                                     MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                                     MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                                     MYSQL_DATENBANK
                                    );

                $sql = "SELECT date, artist, releasename, itunes, ical, directdl FROM upcoming ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40";

                $db_erg = $db_link->query( $sql );

                function ausgabe($daten) {
                    echo "<img src='images/icon_cd.png'>";
                    echo "<span class='release_bold'>". $daten->date .":&nbsp;". $daten->artist ."&nbsp;-&nbsp;". $daten->releasename ."</span><br />";
                    echo "<span class='release_grey'><a href='". $daten->itunes ."'>iTunes (Pre-Order)</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href='". $daten->ical ."'>Create iCal-Event</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href='". $daten->directdl ."'>Download</a></span><br />";
                }

                while($daten = $db_erg->fetch_object()) {
                    ausgabe($daten);
                }

                ?>
```

When I try to embed the both other tables, the page shows only a white screen. The question is, how can I embed three different mysql tables on different positions via php?

Thanks

Link to project: http://toegraphics.de/music/

Comment: you show only the first table. where does the error happen?

Comment: at the second request - added whole code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be in the beginning of the file, not in the 3rd case.

```
require_once ('mysql-config.php');

$db_link = mysqli_connect (
                                     MYSQL_HOST, 
                                     MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                                     MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                                     MYSQL_DATENBANK
                                    );
```

Otherwise $db_link is not defined, and will give an error when calling the following method on an undefined object. The reason you see nothing, is probably because your webserver error messages are disabled.

```
$db_link->query( $sql );
```

Also you define function 3 times. you must use different names.

```
function ausgabe($daten)
```

Comment: doesn't make any sense. but i can call the different scripts with 
<?php require_once ('album.php'); ?>

Then, the first script will work, and I can see the page, but the page doesn't load the other scripts.

Comment: is this  all one file? also you define function ausgabe($daten) 3 times!

Comment: no three different files: single.php, album.php, upcoming.php.

see now: http://toegraphics.de/music/ scripts loaded with require_once.

but the page cuts the divs: http://pastebin.com/DSSJC3YM

Comment: be more specific in your code. how can we know you talk of 3 different files? and how are these 3 files loaded?

Comment: all three files are loaded with require_once, check out the pastebin in my last comment, and the project now: http://toegraphics.de/music/

Comment: you cannot have the function ausgabe defined 3 times in the same scope. use different names. also enable logs to see what is wrong.